# JSHint error message in Brackets for Angular 1 service named with lower case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint, adobe-brackets

Using Brackets with JSHint extension and Angular.

For this Angular service script JSHint shows no error:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('randomApp')
        .service('Ab', Ab);

    Ab.$inject = [];

    function Ab() {
        this.getWorkflows = function () {
            return;
        };
    }
})();
```

but if I change the name of the service to lower case:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('randomApp')
        .service('ab', ab);

    ab.$inject = [];

    function ab() {
        this.getWorkflows = function () {
            return;
        };
    }
})();
```

an error shows up in JSHint saying that:

If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation it's 'this' value will be undefined

Edit: The error disappears even for lower case if I place the function inside the service declaration:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('randomApp')
        .service('aB', function () {
            this.getWorkflows = function () {
                return;
            };
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start service name with Capital letters, I had the same problem and i solved it by using my service name with Caps.
This is the right way to define a service or a controller : -

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('randomApp')
    .service('Ab', Ab);

Ab.$inject = [];

function Ab() {
    this.getWorkflows = function () {
        return;
    };
}
})();
```

Comment: This recommends using lowercase: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#factory-and-service-names

Comment: but the way i used to declare my service solved my issue , you should try and please let me know if  it's not working